# Async function overload implementaion

Tags: swift

Let's say I have a class with 2 functions with the same logic, but one is synchronous while the second isn't.

```
class Api {
    func readFile() async -> String {
        var result = await fs.readAsync()
        // ... body
        return result
    }
    func readFile() -> String {
        var result = fs.read()
        // ... body
        return result
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have many lines of the same logic inside the `// ... body` part and, therefore, I need to change both of them if I want to fix/change something inside.

Does swift have some sugar for that case? Can I somehow add an async version of the function with less effort? I know, I can move the body part away in the 3rd function, but what if I have several async calls inside?

Comment: If you have several async calls in the body just get rid of the sync why have 2 and block the thread/actor

Comment: I agree with @loremipsum. Put the line `@available(*, deprecated, message: "Prefer async alternative instead")` above the synchronous method, it will display a warning wherever the method is called..

Comment: It would be great, but I need to have a sync method available. I can't just get rid of it.

Comment: Turning sync code into async is not issue just use await Task{sync code here}.value but async to sync goes against the essence of the new Concurrency it will not pass Swift6 muster you would quite literally block/sleep/freeze the thread/actor and cause another chain of issues.

Comment: Are there any other async calls in `// ... body`? If not, just factor it into a different synchronous function to be called both by the async version and the sync version of `readFile()`

Comment: "I can move the body part away in the 3rd function, but what if I have several async calls inside?" make it into 4/5 private submethods if needed, then I guess... I don't think there is another way to do so.